# On production server at one page I am getting Fatal error ActionView::Template::Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting this error " ActionView::Template::Error (bad component(expected host component): ): ", on research on stackoverflow I observed this error is occurring on wrong config of mailer. But I have not configured any mails.

[image: console error log]

Answer (score 0):

From the details shared , the first line indicates error in fetching the data.
A line of action to resolve this could be,

1. first to check the correctness of data fetch using rails console/sandbox environment.

   2. Once point 1 above is sorted out and still error, then have a look at the view and check the rendering/flow.

This will point you to the error.